# Visual Studio Code macOS: error loading OmniSharp: spawn EACCES

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having no luck in trying to make the C# extension work in macOS. When loading the sln file everything seems to load just fine other than OmniSharp. This makes it hard or impossible to work with Visual Studio Code.

Here's the error I get:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 2018-5-4 13:51:51
Target: /PATH/TO/PROJECT/Project.sln

[ERROR] Error: spawn EACCES
```

Which tells very little about what's wrong.

I followed all instructions found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity), including installing Mono SDK but OmniSharp keeps giving this error. I also tried

- to install the extension from a vsix file
- to overwrite the omnisharp folder content with what I found [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/releases)
  All leading to the same error.

When the extension is freshly installed, it automatically downloads the OmniSharp package and successfully installs it.

```
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: darwin, x86_64

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for OSX' (24026 KB) .................... Done!
Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (macOS / x64)' (44057 KB) .................... Done!

Installing package 'OmniSharp for OSX'
Installing package '.NET Core Debugger (macOS / x64)'

Finished
```

Someone suggests to add a+x permissions recursively to the whole project folder (as found in [this official thread](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/526)) but is this really necessary? All files in extensions belong to the same **staff** group as all files in the project do.

I tried this anyway but still *[ERROR] Error: spawn EACCES*

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.23.0 and the OmniSharp's version is 1.14.0.

I should also say that all projects I am trying to open are generated by Unity 3D and I have the Unity Debug extension installed.

I don't know where else to go from here. Would someone be able to give advice on this?